# Вставка даты из Java класса при редактировании формы в html

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet, datetime

Пишу web проект на java сервлетах и JSP. Возникла необходимость редактирования уже заполненной формы, для этого выводится такая же форма, только в `<input>` поля уже заполнены значениями и при желании можно любое редактировать и сохранять.

Возникает проблема только с датой. Ранее заполненная дата не выводится, а появляется лишь пустое поле с календарем, для заполнения заново.

Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли преобразование даты из java класса таким образом, чтобы она подставлялась в `<input type="date">` автоматически. Конкретнее вопрос, к какому виду нужно привести дату в Java классе, чтобы он заполнил данное поле?

**UPDATE:**
На данный момент смирился, и пока представляю дату просто в виде строки. Но таким же способом пытался заполнить поле даты с разными форматами.

```
<%@page import="UserProfile.UserProfile"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Updating</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ page import="IncomingMail.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Locale"%>
    <%
    IncomingMail incomingMail = (IncomingMail) request.getAttribute("incomingMail");
    
    Date resultSendDate = null;
    Date resultSecondFloorDate = null;
    String sendDate = null;
    String secondFloorDate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat oldDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    if (!incomingMail.getSendDate().equals("null")) {
    resultSendDate = oldDateFormat.parse(incomingMail.getSendDate());
    sendDate = newDateFormat.format(resultSendDate);
} else {
resultSendDate = oldDateFormat.parse("01-01-0001");
sendDate = newDateFormat.format(resultSendDate);
}
if (!incomingMail.getSecondFloorDate().equals("null")) {
resultSecondFloorDate = oldDateFormat.parse(incomingMail.getSecondFloorDate());             
secondFloorDate = newDateFormat.format(resultSecondFloorDate);
} else {
resultSecondFloorDate = oldDateFormat.parse("01-01-0001");              
secondFloorDate = newDateFormat.format(resultSecondFloorDate);
}




%>




<form method="post" action="incomingMail?action=submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Тип письма: </>
        <select name="typeMail">
            <%@ page import="IncomingMail.*"%>
            <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
            <% 
            ArrayList<String> typeMail = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("typeMailList");
            for (String values : typeMail) { %>
            <option value="<%= values %>"><%= values %></option>
            <% } %>
        </select></p> 
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Отправитель: </>
            <input type="text" name="sender" value="<%= incomingMail.getSender() %>" list="senderList" placeholder="Отправитель" /> 
            <br><br><br>
            <p>Дата отправления письма: </>
                <input type="text" required name="sendDate" value="<%= sendDate %>" placeholder="Дата отправления письма" />
                <br><br><br>
                <p>Номер письма: </>
                    <input type="text" name="mailNum" value="<%= incomingMail.getMailNum() %>" placeholder="Номер письма" />
                    <br><br><br>
                    <p>Тема письма: </>
                        <input type="text" name="mailTheme" value="<%= incomingMail.getMailTheme() %>" placeholder="Тема письма" />
                        <br><br><br>
                        <p>Дата, присваевыемая при первичной рег. документа: </>
                            <input type="text" name="secondFloorDate" value="<%= secondFloorDate %>" placeholder="Дата, присваевыемая при первичной рег. документа" />
                            <p>Номер письма, присваевыемый при первичной рег. документа: </>
                                <input type="text" name="secondFloorNum" value="<%= incomingMail.getSecondFloorNum() %>" placeholder="Номер письма, присваевыемый при первичной рег. документа" />
                                <br><br><br>
                                <p>Документ: </>
                                    <input name="file" type="file"><br>
                                    <br><br><br>
                                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                                    
                                    <datalist id="senderList">
                                        <%@ page import="IncomingMail.*"%>
                                        <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
                                        <% 
                                        ArrayList<String> senderList = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("senderMailList");
                                        for (String values : senderList) { 
                                        out.println("<option>");
                                            out.println(values); 
                                        out.println("</option>");   
                                    } %>
                                </datalist>
                                
                            </form>
                            
                        </body>
                        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужный формат -> yyyy-MM-dd (например, 2013-01-08)

в классе: `request.setAttribute("date", "2013-01-08");`

на jsp: `<input type="date" value="${requestScope.date}">`

Comment: Пробовал, поле даты оставляет незаполненным

Comment: @МишаковАлександр как ты на jsp получаешь ?

Comment: добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: @МишаковАлександр правил ответ. проверяй

Answer (score 0):

При вставке значения в поле надо использовать формат календаря.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();        
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/datepicker-ru.js"></script>

<p>Дата: <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="23.08.2018"></p>
```